# Apply style resource in drawable xml

Tags: android

I have this in res/values/styles.xml

```
    <style name="ListViewRowBorder" >
        <item name="android:width">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:color">@color/listview_row_stroke_color</item>
    </style>
```

I am able to access color resources.How do i access this style resource in res/drawable/file.xml (shown below)
The way i have tried below does not seem to work.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/list_item_dark_background"/>
        <stroke style="@style/ListViewRowBorder" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think you can use a style for a stroke, please have a look at:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#stroke-element

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use Styles with shapes

As per the [Style dev page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html):

> A style can be applied to an individual View (from within a layout
>   file) or to an entire Activity or application (from within the
>   manifest file).